# Bulk change "Available Product Listing Sort By" for all categories?

Tags: magento-1, sorting, ee-1.12

I have a big Magento Store with about 200 categories. Currently, "Available Product Listing Sort By" for all categories is set to "Use All Available Attributes".

For about 10 categories, I would like to add some more custom attributes, which shouldn't appear in the other categories. Therefore I have to uncheck "Use All Available Attributes" for all categories and choose them manually.

Is there a way to change this for all categories in one step?